# Accessing .VDI Image from Ubuntu VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive

I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed in VirtualBox 4.0.10 on a Windows Vista Home Premium 
32-bit host. I have a hard disk that I have added to the SATA Controller on the VirtualBox
(a .VDI image). My question is, how can I access the files within that hard disk?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the partitions with `sudo fdisk -l` and mount them, also from nautilus.

Comment: How can I mount the hard disk?

Comment: Do you see it with the command above? See their partitions? So you could mount a partition with `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`, for example.